# Different math-style options for different fonts with unicode-math package

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I want to use several math fonts in my document, one of which is Neo Euler. With this font, Latin lowercase is upright, but I want to keep the slanted version for another font:

```
\setmathfont[version=euler,math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[version=bonummath,math-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
```

This doesn't produce any letters when Neo Euler is used:

[image]

If I swap the lines:

```
\setmathfont[version=bonummath,math-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfont[version=euler,math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}
```

Bonum Math becomes upright:

[image]

How can this be fixed? Full MWE (I use LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[version=bonummath,math-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfont[version=euler,math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}


\begin{document}

abc with Bonum: \mathversion{bonummath} $abc$

abc with Euler: \mathversion{euler} $abc$ and \textbf{symup} version: $\symup{abc}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I doubt very much that it is currently possible, you would probably have to make a feature request for unicode-math. Beside this I do find the idea of two math fonts -- and these with so different setup -- in one document rather dubious.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is, indeed. But this is a special document, where I demonstate different fonts and see if the body/heading/math fonts look good with each other.

Comment: Then I would prepare external documents and insert them as graphics -- much less fuss ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer doesn't seem easier to me: having 100500 files is no a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In a Modern Toolchain

This example sets upright math letters, `\symup` and `\symbfup`, to Neo Euler.  It leaves digits and operator names unchanged.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Scale=1.0,
  Ligatures={Common, Discretionary, TeX}]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak},
              script-features={},
              sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler Identities]

This sets the Euler identities in Neo Euler, according to ISO style. Symbolic constants such as i, e and π are set upright, in Neo Euler, and everything else is from a Palatino clone.  Variables are italic, and digits and operator names match the text font.

### In Legacy NFSS

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
% If you also want to load Euler Script and Fraktur, you want mathalfa.

\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerup}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"69}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upe}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"65}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample with pxfonts and eulervm]

This version gives similar output in pdflatex, but does not define a separate upright math alphabet.  Instead, it declares the individual upright constants it needs from `eulervm`.  The encoding is documented in the `amsfonts` User Guide, but is the same as OML.

It is also possible to make the upright font (Euler) the default by loading the right package (`eulervm` or `eulerpx`), and then load a separate `\mathit` alphabet.  However, the LaTeX kernel does not define an upright math alphabet separate from `\mathrm`, like `\symup` in `unicode-math`.